# NullReferenceException on WorkflowInvoker.Invoke()

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm facing an issue that I have no clue what it could be or any hint on how to get more information.

Currently I have a workflow A and on this workflow I have several activivies (custom code activities) and some default ones. On this workflow several other workflows are invoked. One of them, lets call it B when is being invoked the method WorkflowInvoker.Invoke() on the activity that is responsible for invoking the sub workflow (B) throws an NullReferenceException.

One thing to notice is that If I run the workflow B outside A, it runs perfectly, but when runs from A it throws the exception.

All these workflows and activities are loaded dynamically by a web application and I can't seem to be able to debug after the WorkflowInvoker.Invoke().

Another person was able to have it working on a different machine but in theory everything is the same, but I'm thinking that it could be something related to the environment and the dynamic loading from the XAML or something, but I have no clues.

Any thoughts or ideas to try out?

PS: I'm using WF4.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet here how you call workflow B from A.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I figured it out was going on... apparently on a specific scenario one of the workflow variables initializers had a LINQ statement that was having a null value and this was causing the error.

Debug wasn't helpful at all, it didn't provided me any clue on this.